Не работает State в aiogram 3.x
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F, Router, html
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Message, CallbackQuery, InputFile
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.exceptions import TelegramBadRequest    


class Dice(StatesGroup):
    Accept = State()


async def CubeDice(m: types.message, state: FSMContext):
        keyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад", callback_data='back')]
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=keyboard)
        await m.answer("Введите сумму ставки (в USDT): ", reply_markup=reply_markup)
        await state.set_state(Dice.Accept)
        summ = m.text
        return(summ)

Ошибка которую выдает - AttributeError: type object 'State' has no attribute 'set_state'
